# Check for value in database (Login)

Tags: php, mysqli

I made a small code to test the login system it
The first page

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <form action="check.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <input type="text" name="password" />
      <input type="text" name="email" />
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the second

```
<?php 
  $servername = "";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "ahmed2001";
  $db = "html";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
  if(!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  $user = $_REQUEST['username'];
  $pass = $_REQUEST['password'];
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];

  $checkU = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM players WHERE username = $user");


  if ($checkU && mysql_num_rows($checkU) > 0) {
    echo "You have logged in !";
  } else {
    echo "Failed to log in !";
  }
?>
```

But it always give me failed to login while I am copying the data from the database ?!

Comment: Once copy the query in mysql and check whether it's working fine or not....

Comment: Hii @Nezoo... Once change the `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query` and then try it.. I think it may be the issue...

Comment: Yes the database is working well

Comment: @phpfresher and leave the others as well or change anything ?

Comment: Once try this too..
`if(mysqli_num_rows($conn,$checkU)>0)
{
echo "Logged In";
}
else
{
echo "Login Failed";
}`

Comment: already done because it gave to me an error but nothing :(

Comment: Once try putting all the functionality in `if(isset($_POST)){ //Code goes here}`

Comment: From `$user = $_REQUEST['username'];` to till end.. 
`echo "Failed to log in !";
  }`

Comment: more details i am new in php

Comment: Did you try it ? Its not working ?

Comment: Try what explain  more in your first comment

Comment: Hii @Nezoo.. i've posted the whole code... Once try it...

Comment: @Nezoo You've another answer given below; mine. Also make sure you don't have any spaces in your datatable or entered in the input fields, and that everything matches your table. As stated in my answer; if my answer does not work for you, then the problems lies elswhere in your database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

You are mixing MySQL libraries which do not intermix with each other.

Plus, missing quotes around the `$user` variable in the `where` clause.

Strings must be encapsulated in quotes, as well as passing DB connection to the query along with its `mysqli_` equivalent for `mysql_query()` and `mysql_num_row()`, functions that do not intermix with your `mysqli_` connection.

Also this line:

```
if ($checkU && mysqli_num_rows($checkU) > 0)
```

replace it simply with:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($checkU) > 0)
```

Rewrite:

```
<?php 
  $servername = "";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "ahmed2001";
  $db = "html";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
  if(!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  $user = $_REQUEST['username'];
  $pass = $_REQUEST['password'];
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];

  $checkU = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM players WHERE username = '".$user."'") 
            or die(mysqli_error($conn))
  ;


  if (mysqli_num_rows($checkU) > 0) {
    echo "You have logged in !";
  } else {
    echo "Failed to log in !";
  }
?>
```

Plus, in regards to SQL injection,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

Use `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` with `mysqli_query()`.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

If what I have presented in my answer does not solve it, then you have problems elsewhere in your database.

- Check column types and lengths.
- If there is fact data to match the login info.
- Use error checking/reporting.

Sidenote: You are only checking for a username in your query. So, I don't know why you're only checking against a username rather than a combination of a password also.

If this is the case, you will need to add an additional query in your `where` clause.

I.e.:

```
WHERE username = '".$user."' AND password = '".$pass."'
```

if `password` is the column name in your table.

Comment: So i want also to add password so i made 
$check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM players WHERE username = '".$user."' AND password = '".$pass"'")

Comment: So i want also to add password so i made 
$check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM players WHERE username = '".$user."' AND password = '".$pass"'")
but i got
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\AppServ\www\check.php on line 16
this is line 16

Comment: @Nezoo it's because you missed a dot in `'".$pass"'"` --- `$check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM players WHERE username = '".$user."' AND password = '".$pass."'")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You have to encapsulate the data in ''

Also use $_POST when using a post form.

---

```
 <?php 
    $servername = "";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "ahmed2001";
    $db = "html";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
    if(!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $checkU = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM players WHERE username='$user'");


    if ($checkU && mysql_num_rows($checkU) > 0)
    {
    echo "You have logged in !";
    } else {
    echo "Failed to log in !";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hiii @Schalk Keun... Giving the variable in single quotes will not process through it, instead of that we can use it as 

`mysql_query("SELECT username FROM players WHERE username=".$user);`

Comment: True that. I will still suggest that the lookup value be encapsulated in "" to prevent lookup errors with values containing spaces.
so maybe:
`mysql_query('SELECT username FROM players WHERE username="'.$user.'"');`

Comment: @Nezoo you are obviously populating the $servername with the correct details? and not leaving it blank?

Comment: There is other page whoch add the data into the database and it is working ;)

Comment: ok. I think I see what is wrong: you need to use `$checkU = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT username FROM players WHERE username="'.$user.'"');` as you have made a `mysqli_connection()`

Answer (score 0):

Once try with this code..

```
<?php 
  $servername = "";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "ahmed2001";
  $db = "html";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
if(!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
      }
$db=mysqli_select_db($conn,$db) or die("Database Not Found");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $user = $_POST['username'];
  $pass = $_POST['password'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $checkU = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username FROM players WHERE username =".$user) or die("Query Execution Error");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($conn,$checkU) > 0) {
    echo "You have logged in !";
  } else {
    echo "Failed to log in !";
  }
}
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="check.php" method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <input type="text" name="password" />
      <input type="text" name="email" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```